# error in conditional function in cmd batch file

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop, cmd

I have tried the following code to copy the list of files in the filelist.txt file. The result files not copied. I don't know where I made the mistake.

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in (filelist.txt) do echo D|xcopy "E:\share\30\%%i" "C:\Users\jaishankar.a\Desktop\Unit-testing\%%i" /i /z /y /s
```

Comment: What's `echo D` supposed to do? I think that [piping](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) its output (_D_) to `xcopy` only confuses it. If you want to carry 2 commands you might want to use `&`.

Comment: filelist.txt contain list of file names which i want to copy from the directory

Answer (score 0):

This command line should work in the batch file:

```
for /F "delims=" %%I in (filelist.txt) do %SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "E:\share\30\%%~I" "C:\Users\jaishankar.a\Desktop\Unit-testing\" /C /H /I /K /Q /R /Y >nul
```

It copies the files with file name listed in `filelist.txt` from the folder `E:\share\30` to the folder `C:\Users\jaishankar.a\Desktop\Unit-testing`.

It is important to specify as target only the folder name ending with a backslash as otherwise **XCOPY** would ask if target specifies a directory or a file. **XCOPY** interprets here automatically the target as directory because target path ends with a backslash and option `/I` is specified also on command line. That is the reason why no echo command is needed here with the letter to answer the prompt if target specifies a directory or file.

This command line copies also hidden and system files with copying also read-only attribute and overwriting existing file with same name as source file even if it has read-only attribute set.

**XCOPY** creates the target directory tree automatically if this would be necessary on copying the first file.

Also possible for files with no special attributes would be:

```
md "C:\Users\jaishankar.a\Desktop\Unit-testing" 2>nul
for /F "delims=" %%I in (filelist.txt) do copy /Y "E:\share\30\%%~I" "C:\Users\jaishankar.a\Desktop\Unit-testing\" >nul
```

The target directory `C:\Users\jaishankar.a\Desktop\Unit-testing` must already exist on using **COPY** in batch file which is the reason for the first line.

Note: Instead of `C:\Users\jaishankar.a` it is also possible to use `%USERPROFILE%` if the batch file is executed by user `jaishankar.a`.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `copy /?`
- `for /?`
- `md /?`
- `xcopy /?`